# What bibliography style starts with author name in italics?

Tags: bibtex

So I have to write an article for a journal which requires authors use citations so that they look like this: [image]

And they write refs manually in there example...( And I am quite used to bibtex... So I wonder how is this style named so I could use `\bibliographystyle{stylename}`?

Comment: [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) can do that with `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}`

Comment: What other requirements, other than rendering the author's names in italics, does this mysterious referencing style have? Instead of looking for a ready-made `.bst` file, you may be better off acquainting yourself with the `custom-bib` package and its `makebst` utility, which provides a menu-driving approach to creating a `.bst` file from scratch.

Comment: @moewe Is there a way to do such thing for natbib?

Comment: If you want to stay with `natbib`, take Mico's advice.